# How to make text change in game maker?

Tags: game-maker, gml

I have a text that appears, when the game starts. But once the obj_cover is destroyed, I would like another text to appear. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want change one text to another, you can do something like

```
if instance_exists(obj_cover)
    var txt = "text 1";
else
    var txt = "text 2";

draw_text(posx, posy, txt);
```

If you want simple show text when `obj_cover` is destroyed, you can do, for example, this:

Create object `obj_text`. Add to `Create` event:

```
text = "";
```

`Draw` event:

```
// also here you can define color, font, align, etc
draw_text(x, y, text);
```

Now add to `obj_cover`, `Destroy` event:

```
var obj = instance_create(posx, posy, obj_text);
obj.text = "your text";
```

Other way - you can use a variable for checking, is need draw text or not. For example, `Destroy` event of `obj_cover`:

```
global.show_text = false;
```

And somewhere in other object:

```
if global.show_text
    draw_text(posx, posy, "text");
```

etc...
Very many ways possible.